# Why Can't I Reverse All Iterators in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, python-3.8

- I can call `reversed` on a list.
- I can call `reversed` on a range_iterator.
- I can't call `reversed` on a list_iterator.
- I can't call `reversed` on an itertools.accumulate.

Why can I call `reversed` on a list and a range_iterator, but not on a list_iterator or an itertools iterator?

```py
>>> reversed(itertools.accumulate(reversed(x), lambda x, y: x + y))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'itertools.accumulate' object is not reversible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [read the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) you'll see that `reversed` works on any object with the following characteristics:

> has a `__reversed__()` method or supports the sequence protocol (the
>   `__len__()` method and the `__getitem__()` method with integer
>   arguments starting at `0`)

Note, that means *cannot* use `reversed` on a range_iterator, but you can on a regular `range` object.

```
>>> reversed(iter(range(10)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'range_iterator' object is not reversible
>>> reversed(range(10))
<range_iterator object at 0x105bcac90>
```

Also note, you can usually not reverse *iterators* at all, it is *sequence-like* iterables that are generally reversible. Or anything that supports it through the magic-method hook `__reversed__()`, and iterators generally have neither (usually only having support for `__iter__` and `__next__`)

Comment: Makes sense. But wouldn't it make sense for `itertools.accumulate` to support the sequence protocol? Because it's a finite sequence?

Comment: @BtLutz no, `itertools.accumulate` *is not a sequence at all*. It supports neither `__getitem__` nor `len` (and need not be finite)

Comment: makes sense that it wouldn't support __getitem__. The first argument to accumulate is an iterator (infinite in length), not a sequence. Therefore, the result could also be infinite in length. Thanks!